# "why oh why" or "why, oh why"?

Tags: punctuation, interjections

Is this punctuated correctly?

> If happy little bluebirds fly beyond the rainbow,
>   Why oh why can’t I?"

Or should “oh why” be set off by commas?

> If happy little bluebirds fly beyond the rainbow,
>   Why, oh why, can’t I?

Comment: I'm curious...seeing as that is an established lyric from the song "Over the Rainbow", is there a reason you wouldn't look up the punctuation online or did you find conflicting versions of punctuation for the song?

Comment: Because it's a song lyric and *why oh why can't* is four consecutive quavers to be sung as a single rising phrase.

Comment: Be that as it may, @StoneyB, it's traditionally not sung as straight quarter notes and some artistic stylization is usually applied that would make the addition of slight pauses (commas) helpful to the singer.

Comment: @KristinaLopez There's always a big ritard on it, because it's the final phrase, and any artist may perform it with any degree of rubato; but the original and still canonical performance by Judy Garland takes it as written. I think there's a deal of musical symbolism in that tag, with the straining and fluttering giving way finally to an effortless soar on the final phrase.

Comment: All true, @StoneyB, but are you advocating commas or no punctuation between the last 5 words?

Comment: @KristinaLopez If (as appears to be the case) Yip Harburg wrote it without commas, that's the way it should be printed; lyrics are meant to be sung by singers, not read by readers. (And there's really no reason but convention to point it; people don't say it that way, either.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song lyrics famously don't have 'incorrect' punctuation.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be setting off _oh_ by commas as well, now that you’re at it? You would do that in most contexts: “Oh, why can’t I fly like the bluebirds?”. If you consider _oh why_ a parenthetical to be set off by commas, surely it ought to be “If happy little bluebirds fly beyond the rainbow / Why, oh, why, can’t I?”. But what would that do to this bit in _Buenos Aires_ from _Evita_: “Birds fly out of here, so why oh why oh why the hell can’t I?”? You’d end up with “Birds fly out of here, so why, oh, why, oh, why, the hell can’t I?”, which is just dreadful.

Comment: I think (outside of a music lyric) you can punctuate it any way you want.  YOY do people obsess about such things??

Comment: I eagerly await a definitive explication of the proper punctuation of "Why oh why oh why oh why did I ever leave Ohio?" from the 1953 musical _Wonderful Town_.

Comment: @StoneyB - I don't know much about music or singing. Your explanation gave me goosebumps when I thought about it and Judy Garland's singing. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commas after the "why"s are rests, and are needed because Garland shifts from a 2 4 rhythm to a 3 4 rhythm beginning at the two measures I've marked with ||.  (I'm not saying that's in the score, but I've just listened to the song a bunch of times, and I think that's what she does.)

> If |happy |little |bluebirds |fly be|yond the |rainbow, ||why, oh ||why, can't ||I?

Afterthoughts: But maybe the first of those rests comes after "oh" instead of before it. And it should be a 4 4 rhythm, not 2 4.

> If |happy little |bluebirds fly be|yond the rainbow, ||why oh, ||why, can't ||I?

Answer (score -1):

The second one is correctly punctuated; however, it does not require a capital "W".

> If happy little bluebirds fly beyond the rainbow, why, oh why, can't I?

Comment: I think I might have put a semi-colon rather than a comma after 'rainbow'.

Comment: With no sources or even explanations as to _why_ you consider the second correctly punctuated (and presumably thus the first incorrectly punctuated), this seems more like just stating an opinion than giving an actual, factual answer.